# issue with nested for loops c#

Tags: c#

it seems that I'm kinda stuck with an assignment.
I need to use nested for loops to get this outcome:

0****
01***
012**
0123*
01234

but whatever I do I just don't seem to get there.

this is what I coded :

```
int i , j;  
for (i=0; i<=5;i++)
{
    for (j=3; j>= 0; j--)
    {
        Console.Write(j);
        Console.Write("*");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey();
```

but that gives me this outcome :

0*0*0*0*
1*1*1*1*
2*2*2*2*
3*3*3*3*
4*4*4*4*
5*5*5*5*

and it needs to be a nested loop

Comment: ... show us what you have tried then, also this can be done in one loop

Comment: Provide some code

Comment: Start by showing what you tried yourself.

Comment: Please provide the code you already have, if some. If not, please elaborate more. Is your requirement to generate exactly this ouput, or do you need a general advice for a bigger range of numbers?

Comment: The code you have provided would not produce the output you've shown, it should output `3*2*1*0*` 5 times

Comment: You could do one loop for each line, then nested inside do a loop to write out the numbers on that line, followed by another nested loop to write out the stars.  The issue with your code is that you alternate between writing a number and a star in one loop.

Comment: @Imke [check this](http://rextester.com/ALBQ55635)

Comment: @m.rogalski [also this](http://rextester.com/PQTE63175) (doesn't answer question 100% but uses one loop)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Your example is almost perfect, but it still uses one loop. I was focusing more on using 2 loops that's why my example looks ugly.

Comment: @m.rogalski that was my reasoning :P it's helpful but not an outright homework answer, though with the added information given i think it's alright to give a full answer now

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with only one loop:

```
string numbers = "01234";
string stars = "*****";

for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"{numbers.Substring(0, i)}{stars.Substring(i)}");
```

Comment: This wouldnt compile, also even if you added `i++` it wouldnt print 01234

Comment: @ZoranHorvat well if you are posting an answer that doesn't compile (everyone does, especially thanks to FGITW) then expect to get downvotes, it happens sadly

Comment: @Botonomous it didn't it has been edited so that it does

Comment: @Botonomous look at the edit...lol and removing my down-vote now as it works

Comment: Thank you for noting. Looks like I'm hungry :)

Comment: Thank you it does work! but I also need to know how I reach the same outcome but but nested loops. But I think  this answer gave me an idea to do that

Comment: This solution is based on the idea that there is a boundary which divides digits from stars and that boundary moves from 1 to N. That is how I get to a single loop, since there is a single variable that changes.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat This will only compile with **C# 6** and you should mention that. Another thing is that OP wrote **"it needs to be a nested loop"** and your example has not nested loop.